# How can I get consistent javascript syntax highlighting in note-taking apps?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I am trialing a few different note-taking apps for making coding notes. A problem I am running into is that syntax highlighting is inconsistent between various apps. I'm a 'weekend coder', trying to learn things on the side. At this point the main language I'm interested in is javascript. I really like the syntax highlighting in VSCode. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like for me:

[image]

I would like for the syntax highlighting in my note-taking app to appear the same as it does in VS Code. However, as the screenshots below demonstrate, each note-taking app seems to have its own syntax highlighting style. In the samples I also included an example of how inline code is displayed when created using markdown. You can see inline code is also displayed with inconsistent styles.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Is there a way I can take the syntax highlighting style in VSCode and reproduce the same style in other apps? Similarly, is there a way to control the style of inline code created in markdown?

Comment: "Is there a way I can take the syntax highlighting style in VSCode and reproduce the same style in other apps?"—the answer will change by target application. You're going to have to focus on one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. That makes sense. Of the apps I sampled, Notable is one I like a lot. Searching Noteable's Github pages, there's an [issue](https://github.com/notable/notable/issues/719) which says, "Code blocks are now rendered by Monaco ..." Other [issues](https://github.com/notable/notable/issues/167) mention Prism as another source of syntax highlighting in Noteable. I don't see anywhere in the Notable support documents where it explains how to modify the syntax highlighting. Do you have any suggestions where I might look (e.g. in the local files Notable uses on my hard drive)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but there are two major factors here: (a) how the code is parsed and (b) how it is rendered. You can usually fix stuff in the second category pretty easily, but if your problems are in the first category you'll have a much harder time. (If two things are different colours in one application and the same colour in another, that's usually a sign that you're looking at a parsing difference.)